# Under what circumstances can an Eevee be found in a Hidden Grotto?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

There's a rumour that Eevee can be found in a Hidden Grotto in *Pokémon Black/White 2*, although extremely rare.

Is this true? If so, what exactly are the circumstances under which an Eevee can be found?

Comment: They are available in all the grottos, but they are just VERY rare. Especially the female ones.

Answer (score 1):

Eevee do not normally show up in Hidden Grottos - they are, however, currently available in Japan due to some Funfest Missions accessible via Pokemon Centers.  [Source](http://bulbanews.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Japanese_Pok%C3%A9mon_Centers_announce_Eevee_promotion), also [original Japanese](http://www.pokemon.co.jp/info/2012/10/121012_p01.html).

Answer (score 1):

As Shinrai stated, they cannot normally be found in grottos. [Serebii - Grottos](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/hiddengrotto.shtml) is a list of all available Pokemon in grottos, which areas and percentage of encounter rate. Not only does it list which pokemon you can get, it also lists the items you might get. So the rumor you heard is false on a normal basis. Only true during the current event.